# Prove the following by using a contrapositive argument. "Let $f(x)=7-3x$. If $x_1$ $\neq$ $x_2$, then $f(x_1)$ $\neq$ $f(x_2)$"

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This is supposed to be in proof form. I am completely lost as to where to start but this is what I have.
Prove the following by using a contrapositive argument.

Let $$f\left(x\right)=7-3x.$$ Prove If\ $$f\left(x_1\right)=f\left(x_2\right)$$\ then  $$x_1=x_2$$.

$$f(x)=7-3x$$.\    Given
$$f(x_1)=f(x_2)$$  Given
$$7-3x_1=7-3x_2$$  Given
$$7-3x_1+7=7-3x_2+7$$  additive inverse property
$$3x_1=3x_2$$
$$\frac{{3x}_1}{3}=\frac{{3x}_2}{3}$$  multiplicative inverse property
$$x_1=x_2$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please use [MathJax] for formatting your posts.  Does "dne" mean $\neq$?

Comment: Suppose that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. Then $7 - 3x_1 = 7 - 3x_2$. You should manipulate this algebraically to show that $x_1 = x_2$.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me know where to start.

Comment: Do you know what a contrapositive is?  The basic idea is this.  Suppose you have a logical statement.  For an example, I will paraphrase Socrates and say, "If you are human, then you are mortal."  The contrapositive of that statement is "If you are not mortal, then you are not human."  To make the contrapositive, you take the opposite of both sides and switch the order.  This produces a different (but logically equivalent) statement.  So the contrapositive of "If $x_1 \ne x_2$, then $f(x_1) \ne f(x_2)$" is "If $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, then $x_1 = x_2$."

Comment: thank you @sasquires

Answer (score 2):

Here's an interesting solution.

For sake of contradiction, assume that there exists two non equal real numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$, for which $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Since, $f$ is an affine function, its graph will be strictly monotonic, and this forces $x_1=x_2$ which contradicts our assumption.